# Using PHP do/while statement

Tags: php

I'm attempting to write a simple do/while statement, that creates a random number and then checks if that number is below a certain threshold, if it is the while loop should be stopped. However it doesn't seem to work for me and i can't figure out why.

I'm guessing it's going to be something really simple but I have no clue at the moment.

Here is my code, help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your own do-while</title>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $rayBans = rand(0,70);
    $correctPrice = false;
    do {
        echo "<p> Lets hope I can get ray bans for under £30! </p>";
    }
    while ($correctPrice == false);
        if ($rayBans > 30) {
        echo "<p> raybans at $rayBans are too expensive </p>";
        $correctPrice == false;
    }
    else if ($rayBans < 30){
        echo "<p> Finaly got my rayBans for $rayBans </p>";
        $correctPrice == true;
    }


    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code inside `do..while` will be looped, everything after it is only executed when the loop exits. Since you're not changing any state inside your loop, it'll loop endlessly.

Comment: Thanks, your comments helped my understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Comparing we should be using `==` while assigning the value to a variable we need `=` so in your case

```
do 
{
//You should write something so that $correctPrice becomes true
//as of now it seems to be a infinite loop
echo "<p> Lets hope I can get ray bans for under £30! </p>";
}while ($correctPrice == false);
```

I believe you need to do this

```
<?php
    $correctPrice = false;
    do 
    {
        $rayBans = rand(0,70);
        echo "<p> Lets hope I can get ray bans for under £30! </p>";
        if ($rayBans > 30) 
        {
            echo "<p> raybans at $rayBans are too expensive </p>";
            $correctPrice = false;
        }
        else if ($rayBans < 30)
        {
            echo "<p> Finaly got my rayBans for $rayBans </p>";
            $correctPrice = true;
        }       
    }while ($correctPrice == false);

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

correct your code put you conditions in do-while loop

```
    echo "<p> Lets hope I can get ray bans for under £30! </p>";
    $correctPrice = false;
    do {
        $rayBans = rand(0,70);
        if ($rayBans > 30) {
            echo "<p> raybans at $rayBans are too expensive </p>";
            $correctPrice = false;
        }
        else if ($rayBans < 30){
            echo "<p> Finaly got my rayBans for $rayBans </p>";
            $correctPrice = true;
        }


    }
    while ($correctPrice == false);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I realised I was creating an infinite loop

Comment: This still is a infinite loop. by which way `$correctPrice == false;` this can assign or change the value to come out of the loop.